# Do we have the following isomorphism for $\mathcal{Ext}$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be a smooth variety (over $\mathbb{C}$) and $\Delta: X \rightarrow X \times X$ be the diagonal embedding and $p_1: X\times X\rightarrow X, ~p_2: X\times X\rightarrow X$ be the projections to the first and second components. Let $E$ be a finite dimensional vector bundle on $X$. We define
$$
E_{\Delta}:=\Delta_*E
$$
to be a sheaf on $X\times X$. In particular we have $\mathcal{O}_{\Delta}:=\Delta_*\mathcal{O}$. We have the sheaf Ext functor $\mathcal{Ext}$ on $X\times X$.

$\bf{My~question}$ is: do we have the isomorphism
$$
{Rp_1}_*\mathcal{Ext}_{X\times X}^{\bullet}(E_{\Delta},E_{\Delta})\cong  
{Rp_1}_*\mathcal{Ext}_{X\times X}^{\bullet}(\mathcal{O}_{\Delta},\mathcal{O}_{\Delta})\otimes \mathcal{End}(E) ?
$$

I know that when $X$ is affine, they are isomorphic since $E$ is then free. But does it also hold in the general case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $E \cong \Delta^*p_1^*(E)$ since $p_1\circ\Delta = 1_X$. Therefore by the projection formula
$\Delta_*E = \Delta_*\Delta^*p_1^*(E) = p_1^*(E)\otimes\Delta_*O_X$, hence
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{Ext}(\Delta_*E,\Delta_*E) & 
= \mathcal{Ext}(p_1^*(E)\otimes\Delta_*O_X,p_1^*(E)\otimes\Delta_*O_X) \\
& = p_1^*(E^*)\otimes p_1^*(E)\otimes\mathcal{Ext}(\Delta_*O_X,\Delta_*O_X) = \\
& = p_1^*\mathcal{End}(E)\otimes\mathcal{Ext}(\Delta_*O_X,\Delta_*O_X),
\end{align*}
hence by the projection formula
\begin{align*}
Rp_{1*}\mathcal{Ext}(\Delta_*E,\Delta_*E) 
& = Rp_{1*}(p_1^*\mathcal{End}(E)\otimes\mathcal{Ext}(\Delta_*O_X,\Delta_*O_X)) \\ 
& = \mathcal{End}(E)\otimes Rp_{1*}\mathcal{Ext}(\Delta_*O_X,\Delta_*O_X)).
\end{align*}

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much Sasha!